# Trigger function not working/ SQL statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Im working on a database for school, everything is working except the triggers.
For example:

```
create or replace TRIGGER T_CATEGORY
  before insert on GAMECATEGORY
  for each row
BEGIN 
  select G_Category_ID_SEQ.nextval into new.Category_ID from dual;
END;
```

its giving the SQL statement ignored and its not creating the triggers?
Is there anyone who can help me? :D

:EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE LIVESTREAM
(
Stream_ID                    number(13),
LivestreamURL                varchar2(50),
primary key(Stream_ID, LivestreamURL),
Channel_ID                   number(13) not null,
Category_ID                 number(13) not null,
Title                       varchar2(50) not null,              
Organisation_Name           varchar2(50),
Viewers                     number(13) not null,
LivestreamStatus            varchar2(10)   check (UPPER(LivestreamStatus) IN ('ONLINE','OFFLINE')),
Followers                   number(13) not null,
"Views"                     number(13) not null

);
ALTER TABLE LIVESTREAM ADD constraint FK_LIVESTREAM_Category_ID foreign key(Category_ID) REFERENCES GAMECATEGORY(Category_ID)on delete cascade;
ALTER TABLE LIVESTREAM ADD constraint FK_LIVESTREAM_Channel_ID foreign key(Channel_ID) REFERENCES USERCHANNEL(Channel_ID)on delete cascade;


CREATE SEQUENCE LIVESTREAM_Stream_ID_SEQ
  start with 1
  increment by 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_LIVESTREAM
  before insert on LIVESTREAM
  for each row
BEGIN 
  select LIVESTREAM_Stream_ID_SEQ.nextval into :new.Stream_ID from dual;
END;
/
```

When i insert the data into the table it gives me this error:

```
INSERT INTO LIVESTREAM(LivestreamURL, Channel_ID, Category_ID, Title, Organisation_Name, Viewers, LivestreamStatus, Followers, "Views")
VALUES('http://www.twitch.tv/nightblue3, 2, 1,Next Stream: Friday @ 4 AM PST / 7 AM EST / NOON GMT, The Round Table, , OFFLINE, 1052215, 115257581')
Error at Command Line : 253 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: What kind of entity is `GAMECATEGORY`?

Comment: this is the table its using:`CREATE TABLE GAMECATEGORY
(
Category_ID                 number(13) primary key,
CategoryName               varchar2(50) not null,
ViewerCount                number(13) not null
);`

Comment: You can simplify sequence assignment to `:new.Stream_ID := LIVESTREAM_Stream_ID_SEQ.nextval`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new should be :new.

Comment: I changed it, but its compiling some of the code. There is still triggers who are compiling but with errors? these errors say the SQL statement is ignored

Comment: Is there some more information (Previous or next line?)? Or only the SQL statement ignored.

Comment: Ill show the create table, the trigger and the sequence of the table thats not working in the headanswer above

Comment: Its giving this as shown in the question EDIT: ORA-00947

Comment: The values part should look like  VALUES ('A','B','C') and not like VALUES ('A,B,C')

Comment: Also please do not use , , this is not valid if you have emty value you should use , NULL , .

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're inserting this whole string: `'http://www.twitch.tv/nightblue3, 2, 1,Next Stream: Friday @ 4 AM PST / 7 AM EST / NOON GMT, The Round Table, , OFFLINE, 1052215, 115257581'`
into the LivestreamURL column alone. You must change your query to this:

```
  INSERT INTO LIVESTREAM(LivestreamURL, 
        Channel_ID, Category_ID, 
        Title, Organisation_Name, 
        Viewers, LivestreamStatus, 
        Followers, "Views")
  VALUES
     ('http://www.twitch.tv/nightblue3', 
        2, 1,
        'Next Stream: Friday @ 4 AM PST / 7 AM EST / NOON GMT', 
        'The Round Table', , 
        'OFFLINE', 1052215,
        115257581)
```

Then change your triggers into this:

```
  CREATE  TRIGGER T_LIVESTREAM
    before insert on LIVESTREAM
    for each row
  BEGIN 
     if :new.Stream_ID is null then
    :new.Stream_ID := LIVESTREAM_Stream_ID_SEQ.nextval;
    end if;
  END;
  /

  create or replace TRIGGER T_CATEGORY
     before insert on GAMECATEGORY
     for each row
  BEGIN 
     if :new.Category_ID is null then
     :new.Category_ID := G_Category_ID_SEQ.nextval;
     end if;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: The sequence assignment can be simplified to `:new.Stream_ID := LIVESTREAM_Stream_ID_SEQ.nextval;`

Comment: I applied it @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks